# Issue with compiling neo4j code with neo4j go driver

Tags: go, neo4j

I am trying to run the sample code available at (https://neo4j.com/developer/go/) using golang neo4j driver but running into compiling issues.

I have build the seabolt 1.7.4 from source.
Have the following variables in place
PKG_CONFIG_PATH pointing to seabolt-1.7.4/build/dist/share/pkgconfig
OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/seabolt-1.7.4/build/dist/lib

When I try to build my code with command
env GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" --tags seabolt_static -o bin/user users/user.go

I get the following error

github.com/neo4j-drivers/gobolt
../pkg/mod/github.com/neo4j-drivers/gobolt@v1.7.4/connector_worker.go:30:14: undefined: Config
../pkg/mod/github.com/neo4j-drivers/gobolt@v1.7.4/connector_worker.go:31:15: undefined: seaboltConnector

Can anyone point me in right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been the source of a big issue for me too, but I eventually sorted it out.

The issue is that the lib you download from their [repo](https://github.com/neo4j-drivers/seabolt/releases) is most likely linked to a version of openssl you don't have installed. So you likely need to either compile it yourself so it's relevant to your current OS and architecture, or you need to manually edit the path of the dynamically linked libraries so that it's correct, with nm for example if you're on macOS.

Simply put, you need to make libseabolt available on your working environment first.

It's safe to assume it's a pain in the ass for deploying stuff properly, I had to do hacks here and there to be able to deploy stuff with docker consistently using this driver.

Good luck :)